# How correctly pass arguments to a function from another function that are in a multiprocessing

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a Clock/IN-Clock/OUT device on RPI zero, device will have 2 physical buttons (red and green) for clock in or out, an 2X16 LCD display and a RFID reader, it will register all data to a mySQL DB, I've created functions that constantly will: read from RFID, check buttons, and display date/time to LCD, that's why I use multiprocessing to parallelize all functions
The PROBLEM is that I'm unable to pass variable from one function to another

I tried global variable- no luck

I tried to put 'return' in readdb() function but that reads just one time
Also if I pass readdb() as argument to p3 = Process(target=greenbutton, args=(readdb(), )) program will freeze

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from mfrc522 import SimpleMFRC522
import MySQLdb
import I2C_LCD_driver
import time


mylcd = I2C_LCD_driver.lcd()
reader = SimpleMFRC522()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)


def timedisplay():
    while True:
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 1)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Time: %s" %time.strftime("%H:%M"), 1)
        time.sleep(3)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 1)
        mylcd.lcd_display_string("Date: %s" %time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"), 1)
        time.sleep(3)


def readdb(): #will extract data from DB that coresponds to rfid key scaned

    while True:
        try:

               idc, text = reader.read()

        finally:
                GPIO.cleanup()

        # Open database connection
        db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","pi","raspberry","mydb" )

        # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        cursor = db.cursor()

        sql = "SELECT * FROM staffs WHERE key_id = '%d'" %idc

        try:
           # Execute the SQL command
           cursor.execute(sql)
           # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
           results = cursor.fetchall()
           for row in results:
              #global idc
              idc = row[0]
              key_id = row[1]
              name = row[2]
              # Now print fetched result
              print "id=%s,key_id=%s,name=%s" % (idc, key_id, name,) #prints in console key data
              mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 2) #clears second row of lcd
              mylcd.lcd_display_string(name, 2) #prints nam from database 

        except:
           print "Error: unable to fecth data"

            # disconnect from server
        db.close()
        return idc


def greenbutton(v):
    GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(27)
        if input_state == False:
            mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 2)
            print('GREEN Button Pressed')
            time.sleep(0.2)
        if input_state == False:
            db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","pi","raspberry","mydb" )

            # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
            cursor = db.cursor()
            #v=readdb()
            sql = "INSERT INTO clocking (`staff_id`, `clock_in_flag`) VALUES ('%s','%d')" %(v, 1)

            try:
        # Execute the SQL command
                cursor.execute(sql)
                mylcd.lcd_display_string("Clocking IN", 2)
                time.sleep(3)
                mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 2)
            except:
                print "Error: unable to fecth data"

        # disconnect from server
            db.commit()
            db.close()
            #return

    #return   

def redbutton(v):
    GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
    while True:
        input_state = GPIO.input(22)
        if input_state == False:
            mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 2)
            print('RED Button Pressed')
            time.sleep(0.2)
        if input_state == False:
            db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","pi","raspberry","mydb" )

            # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
            cursor = db.cursor()
            #v=readdb()
            sql = "INSERT INTO clocking (`staff_id`, `clock_in_flag`) VALUES ('%s','%d')" %(v, 0) 

            try:
        # Execute the SQL command
                cursor.execute(sql)
                mylcd.lcd_display_string("Clocking OUT", 2)
                time.sleep(3)
                mylcd.lcd_display_string("                ", 2)
            except:
                print "Error: unable to fecth data"

        # disconnect from server
            db.commit()
            db.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':

 while True:
  p1 = Process(target=timedisplay)
  p1.start()
  p2 = Process(target=readdb)
  p2.start()
  p3 = Process(target=greenbutton, args=(readdb(), )) # this way will not work
  p3.start()
  p4 = Process(target=redbutton, args=(1, )) # 1 is just for test and it works
  p4.start()
  p1.join()
  p2.join()
  p3.join()
  p4.join()
```

Please give me advises how I can fix that

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem (i.e. without all the unrelated stuff, like accessing a database).

Comment: You can in any case, store a scanned idc in the database. Use a table that logs the rfids scanned with a timestamp. When a button is pressed, you search for the latest entries in this table. This also allows you to 'timeout' scans. Eg. after 1 minute, the last IDC is not valid anymore and when a button is pressed, nothing happends.